# Flutter Dropdownformfield

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How do I style the dropdownformfield in flutter? I am using this dropdownformfield package. And I don't see a way to style the dropdown somehow. I am trying to style like box decoration property of a container.

Here is the link to the pub_dev: https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_formfield

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DropdownButtonField` which includes in material package without any external dependancy and style it with `InputDecoration` like this:

```
          value: snapshot.['item 1', 'item 2'],
                        items: snapshot.data
                            .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                                  child: Text(e),
                                  value: e,
                                ))
                            .toList(),
                        onChanged: (val) {},
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Course',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                      );
```